# Several calls to the same function makes byte array corrup?

Tags: c#, debugging, uwp, udp

I have a strange behaviour in a function that sometimes gets an array changed somehow during execution. The function is for UDP message decoding and I make calls to this function quite frequently. Mostly it succeeds but every now and then I get the first part of one message mixed with second part of another. The strange thing I think is that I try to first copy the entire message to a new byte array. I check so that the new byte array is correct (which it always is) and then only use the newly created byte array. But later in the code suddenly this byte array has became corrupt.

See the code that is behaving strange below. The code is for a UWP app, written in C# in visual studio.

```
private void unmaskMSG(State so)
{            
   byte[] readBytes = so.buffer;
   //Same ID at pos 1 and last position to validate the message is not corrupt
   if (readBytes[1] != readBytes[readBytes[0] - 1])
   {
      //Check the ID first and last, might not be necessary since the copy is made in one command.                 
      RecievFailedCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
       //some function code skipped. I only read from readBytes array from now on...
       
       msg101Recieved(readBytes)
    }
}

private void msg101Recieved(byte[] data)
{         
   //Same ID at pos 1 and last position to validate the message is not corrupt
   if (data[1] == data[data[0] - 1] && data[1] == 101)
   {
      //Does some functions...
                
   }
   else
   {
      //This should not happen but I still get here from time to time! How!?
   }
}
```

I put a breakpoint at the position that I think never should be reached. Below is a picture of when the program has breaked at that very position. When I look at the data array at this point it shows values that should not make it breake but obviously it has reached the else statement! Really confusing. How can the data that I am observing during the break be different from what the program has used?

If I use wireshark at the same time to look at the UDP data another message with different data (not 101 at position 1) is sent shortly after the 101 message. if I don´t make the extra check in msg101received() the last part of the databyte will be from this next message.

[image]

Comment: You are using the value of an element as index? `data[data[0] - 1]` Does the first element contains the length?

Comment: A, the screenshot explains it

Comment: Yes you are correct. Index 0 is the length :). Index 1 and the last index is then my message ID.

Comment: You are sure the `so.buffer`  is not changed? (by other threads)

Comment: I recomment to put the `data[0] - 1` in a variable first, it would be more debuggable.

Comment: Yes in fact I think my problem is that the so.buffer is being changed. Am I copying the array wrong? My intention is to make readArray to a new array so that I no longer use the so.buffer. I am not very used in working with arrays. Is the readArray = so.buffer just creating a pointer?

Comment: You didn't made a copy of the array, _(readArray = so.buffer)_ only a copy of the reference . [Array copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0) So, you have to make a copy ;-)   You could also try `var readArray = so.buffer.ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks for the help! A little embarrasing that the mistake was my use of an array :)! I changed the function to: 
            byte[] readBytes = new byte[255];
            Array.Copy(so.buffer, readBytes, 255);
This seems to be working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was that I never copied the array. The so.buffer could be changed from other places. Changed the declaration of my array to:

```
 byte[] readBytes = new byte[255];
 Array.Copy(so.buffer, readBytes, 255);
```

Thanks to Jeroen van Langen!